# Ajax Post not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, ajax, mozilla

I have a site where when the user clicks update, I send all the values that need to be updated to a php page that runs the UPDATE database query. I use Ajax to transfer the data to php page. The update is working in Chrome and Internet Explorer but it isn't working in Mozilla. I ran firebug and realized that the request isn't even being made to the server and I don't really know why

Here is the my Ajax Code

```
$(function() {
            $("#editGameBtn").click(function(){
                var gameId = $('#editGameId').val();
                var newTime = $('#editTime').val();
                var newDate = $('#editDate').val();
                var newGround = $('#editGround').val();
                var newHomeTeam = $('#editHomeTeam').find(":selected").text();
                var newAwayTeam = $('#editAwayTeam').find(":selected").text();

                   if(gameId === "" || newTime === "" || newDate === "" || newGround === ""|| newHomeTeam === ""|| newAwayTeam === "" )
                   {
                       alert("Please Select A game to Edit");
                   }
                    else{
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "updateGame.php",
                           data: { gameId: gameId , newTime: newTime, newDate: newDate, newHomeTeam: newHomeTeam, newAwayTeam: newAwayTeam, newGround: newGround}
                          }).done(function(msg) {
                                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                          });
                    }

            });
        });
```

Comment: try with async:false and dataType:"html"

Comment: Any error in console? Can you put an `alert("clicked");` as the first statement of your button click event listener?

Comment: Niranjan - Tried it and didn't work
Burton - The click event listener is working fine and even the if statement is working, its just the ajax part that isn't

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to fix it but don't really know what the error was and why the solution fixes it.Hopefully someone can explain how does the change I made fix the error. Anyways, so all I had to do was preventDefault and everything worked fine.

Here is the working version of the code

```
$(function() {
    $("#editGameBtn").click(function(e){
        var gameId = $('#editGameId').val();
        var newTime = $('#editTime').val();
        var newDate = $('#editDate').val();
        var newGround = $('#editGround').val();
        var newHomeTeam = $('#editHomeTeam').find(":selected").text();
        var newAwayTeam = $('#editAwayTeam').find(":selected").text();
        e.preventDefault();
           if(gameId === "" || newTime === "" || newDate === "" || newGround === ""|| newHomeTeam === ""|| newAwayTeam === "" )
           {
               alert("Please Select A game to Edit");
           }
            else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "updateGame.php",
                    data: { gameId: gameId , newTime: newTime, newDate: newDate, newHomeTeam: newHomeTeam, newAwayTeam: newAwayTeam, newGround: newGround}

                  }).done(function(msg) {
                       window.location.reload(true);
                  });
            }

    });
});
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess that `$("#editGameBtn")` refers to a button that, when clicked, submits an HTML form. Also, it's better to have the AJAX event trigger on form submit (what if someone hits the enter key on one of the form fields to submit the form?).